# Page.Tostring() behaves a bit weird in .net 1.1?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-1.1

I have a control where I have to check in which page I am, so I can set a certain variable accordingly.

```
string pageName = this.Page.ToString();
switch (pageName)
{
case "ASP.foo_bar_aspx": doSomething(); break;
default: doSomethingElse(); break;
}
```

this works fine locally and on some developmentservers, however when I put it live, It stopped working because I don't get `ASP.foo_bar_aspx` but `_ASP.foo_bar_aspx`
(notice the underscore in the live version)
Why does it act that way, Can I set it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant rely on auto generated names. Use types instead, eg:

```
if (Page is FooBar) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

That seems like a really dodgy way of getting the current request. Have you tried using `HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath` or another `HttpContext.Current.Request...` variable instead?

Comment: Or System.IO.Path.GetFileName(HttpContext.Current.Request.FilePath) if you just want the filename